# CIVI mail - URLs inserted directly into an email template do not direct the user to the correct web page

Tags: civimail, templates

I inserted a url into a CIVI email template - On testing the email, clicking the link which has not changed it re-directs the user to our site and gives an Error 404 page not found.

**https://www.digital10.io/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=366&qid=586**
Any experience of this behaviour we are on civi 5.24.5? pending upgrade to 5.29 but having issues, reluctant to do so. We are sending via a Sparkpost plugin.

Comment: Whats is your wordpress version?

Comment: word press version 5.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround if you make sure that the URL is not tagged as such then if comes through in the email ok and unchanged, this does not solve the issue if you want to mask the url and provide text to describe the link

Answer (score 1):

If you are running WP 5.5.x or later you need CiviCRM 5.26 or later (5.28 is the security release).

The details are here: https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice